# Code generation with Machine learning

Tags: code-generation, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-network

I am very interested in machine learning. i have an idea to develop a program which can generate a source code according to a given standards. for example if i have trained the system to how to write something to console and the standard way of using variables then it should be able to generate a source code for anything which i ask to print something to the console, likewise. Is there any resources source codes or existing open source projects?

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in [Genetic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming). It's a genetic algorithm that operates directly on programs.

The demo I saw used Lisp (Common Lisp, I think), which is a natural fit, but any language with `eval` should be decently easy to use.

The Wikipedia page lists a [whole pile of implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming#Implementations), many of them open source, so you should be able to start there.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like this is would be a Constraint Satisfaction [CSPs] or Search Problem, these approaches would probably be your best bet:

1. Genetic Algorithm
2. Some sort of goal seaking heuristic [with negative/positive reenforcements]
3. The algorithms that are under the CSP category.